# Need: Version control - install with only ftp/mysql access

Tags: mysql, svn, version-control, ftp, version

I would like to host my own version control on the server I already pay for. I don't have shell access, but I can use ftp (obviously) and mysql. Are there any version control solutions that can run with only these?

Comment: Are you trying to host a repository on your server account or use version control to manage the files on your server? I can't tell what you want to do from how your asked your question.

Comment: I need a repo for my c++ project. I asked support about it and they said subversion isn't installed because of the use of SSH and possible problems with SSH and security. Without SSH access I can't install subversion but I need some version control that works without SSH access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Subversion or CVS will work without software installation. Can you mount your account as a file share/network drive? If so [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Choosing_a_publishing_method) would work. You could keep your master repo in the folder and clone it onto your local hard drive for real work. If you're just looking for a remote repository solution, you might be able to use Mercurial or Git with DropBox in the same way.

This is just my opinion, but if any provider ever told me they *don't* support SSH because of security I would immediately cancel my account and get a new provider. Let me guess: they only do Windows server hosting?

If you need to keep your project private you could always use a paid GitHub or BitBucket account as well, but that doesn't solve the problem of hosting on your existing account.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, I found that Assembla allows a free private svn (free because you don't get to use bug trackers and other advanced features I won't be needing). 2GB space. I'll probably be using this service.

Comment: I know some folks who use Unfuddle for this too (http://unfuddle.com/), so it looks like you've got some options... they've even got Git hosting. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! It seems that unfuddle limits free users to 3 or so team members while assembla free users get unlimited. There is also a wikipedia page comparing services like these:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities

In the table theres a spot for "private branch". Hope this helps anyone else looking for a good source code hosting place.

Answer (score 1):

Straight out of git's man page:

> Git natively supports ssh, git, http, https, ftp, ftps, and rsync protocols.

Comment: On the git page, it seems that I would need to download and run a package on the server. I don't have the ability to to this with my host.

Comment: Try creating a local Git repository on your hard drive and uploading the files to your account FTP. You may then be able to clone the project back down via FTP. But basic FTP has some pretty serious limitations (no encryption, firewall problems) so I'd say use that method only as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync works over FTP, so you could have a local folder that represents what you want on the host, and then use rsync to deploy it.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, but it does work over SFTP, which you may well have access to. If not, there are other similar utilities that do work over FTP (such as lftp).